# change account firebase for android

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I am not able to use the database of the firebase i have because I do not have access to a very long time I have forgotten my password and cannot access it and I want to change the database for the application from my old account to use the database account

Comment: Do you want to use services of both accounts? Lets say auth from the old account and RTD from the new account?

Comment: No @cutiko i want to use services form new account only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the project folders a `google-services.json` file. Then do it manually or use the Firebase assistant

Manually: With your Firebase account create a project, add an Android app, and download the new google-service.json to the root of app folder

Firebase Assistant: Go to menu/tools/Firebase and follow the steps